# Exam environment: Alignment of subparts' label

Tags: exam

Is it possible to change the alignment of the `subparts` labels in the `exam` class?

I have changed my labels with the `\renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}` so that it shows (i), (ii), etc. in brackets as I want. However instead of my desired left-aligned `subparts` labels it is right-aligning them.

Is it possible to change this so that the (i), (ii), (iii) etc. labels are left-aligned?

Answer (score 2):

You need to redefine the `\makelabel` macro, but only within the `subparts` environment. Fortunately, the [exam document class](http://ww.ctan.org/pkg/exam) provides the `\subpartshook` macro for just such a purpose.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}
\renewcommand\subpartshook{\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil }}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part
\begin{subparts}
\subpart
\subpart
\subpart
\end{subparts}
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```