# How to customize horizontal alignment of questions, parts, subparts,... of the exam document class?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, numbering, lists, exam

I am working with `exam` document class preparing tests for my students. As known `exam` document class has its own internal numbering system for lists which hierarchical are `questions`, `parts`,`subparts`, `subsubparts` and so on. I would like to change the horizontal alignment of nested lists in a way that the most left point of the label of next level numbering list to be perfectly aligned with the first letter of the text of the previous (or parent) level. For this to be achived at first has to change the alignment of labels of each level from the default `right` option to `left`. I succeeded to that, getting help from this [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153788/exam-environment-alignment-of-subparts-label) (line 16 of code below). This I can't succeed is the alignment of text of parts level to be the same, as you can see the sixth level of parts (line 28 of code) is different. How can I achieve my task for all levels of numbering? Please keep the Greek letters of labels, as the width of labels with Greek letters are different than with latin letters.

The code so far is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\renewcommand\textdexiakeraia{}
\renewcommand\textstigma{\textsigma\texttau}
\renewcommand\textStigma{\textSigma\textTau}
\renewcommand\subpartlabel{(\thesubpart)}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}}
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil }}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question 
        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[line width=0.5pt](0,0.5) -- (0,-12);\textlatin{First question}
            \begin{parts}
                \part 
                \textlatin{Fisrt part question}
                \part \textlatin{Second}
                \part \textlatin{Third}
                \part \textlatin{Fourth}
                \part \textlatin{Fifth}
                \part \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[line width=0.5pt](0,0.5) -- (0,-12);\textlatin{Sixth}
                    \begin{subparts}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Fisrt subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Second subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Third subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Fouth subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Fifth subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \textlatin{Sixth subpart question}
                        \subpart 
                        \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\draw[line width=0.5pt](0,0.5) -- (0,-12);\textlatin{Seventh subpart question}
                            \begin{subsubparts}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Fisrt subsubpart question}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Second subsubpart question}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Third subsubpart question}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Fourth subsubpart question}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Fifth subpart question}
                                \subsubpart
                                \textlatin{Sixth subsubpart question}
                            \end{subsubparts}
                    \end{subparts}
            \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it works:
Add to the preamble of the document the above code:

```
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil }}
\renewcommand{\subpartshook}{%
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil }}
\renewcommand{\subsubpartshook}{%
    \renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil }}
```

This is for the first four levels of numbering. If you need it for more you continue the above code with similar way.